# Does redis pubsub guarantee messages being delivered in sequence?

Tags: redis

If publisherA publish one message before publishB. Is it guaranteed that a subscriber will receive messages in the same sequence i.e. message of publisherA will be received first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of messages delivered by Redis is determined by the order of the messages' arrival/publishing. If publisherA's message is received and handled before that of publisherB's, then the messages will arrive in order to the client (ensured by the TCP stack).